# Memory Segments of a Program in C

Tags: c, linux, memory

I'm looking for a tutorial describing about the various memory segments of a C program like code segment, data segment etc and what type of information is stored into them (i.e. where global, static, automatic etc variables are stored and why?).

--Ravi

Comment: Which platform(s) are you interested in?

Comment: linux but any other will be fine too.

Comment: x86 but again if it coverts others then it will be good

Answer (score 4):

Try reading this: [Linkers & Loaders](http://www.iecc.com/linker/). This is the online copy of a wonderful book by John Levine, which delves into these things.

You will also benefit by reading more about [ELF format](http://www.linuxjournal.com/node/1060/print). [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) has links to more articles about the same.